# How to properly scale Azure cloud service with worker roles for performance?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

I split one Azure cloud service into multiple cloud services assuming this would help performance issues, but after I'm done with the implementations and I'm increasing the number of instances i.e. scaling up for every cloud service I'm still having performance worse than single cloud service. Scaling up doesn't seem to bring positive effect. I have different queues across every cloud service, that's one area I can think of causing this problem, but why scaling up doesn't work at all?

Comment: Without knowing what exactly you cloud services actually DO, there's not much anyone is going to be able to offer.  Provide a detailed explanation of what your cloud services do, include relevant code, and describe exactly what the performance issue is (disk, CPU, memory) and what your expectations are.

Comment: I've three cloud services worker roles working one instances giving me the same results as increasing the number of instances for these worker role.
simply put increasing number of instances are not improving any processing time, any idea?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your queue setup?  Is each instance reading from the same queue?

Comment: every cloud service has two queues read/write, sharing same storage backend and azure sql db
e.g. service 1 I1,O2
service 2 I2, O3
serice 3 I3, O4

Comment: Shouldn't you be hitting the same queues from all instances of the cloud service?  Otherwise the scaling has no effect.

Comment: @BrendanGreen can you share some docs for this please

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh528527.aspx

Comment: @BrendanGreen I agree with you in general but link is mainly for service bus which is different from cloud service and worker roles

Comment: But you're communicating with the cloud services over some kind of message bus, right?  If you want the scaling of the worker roles to have am impact, they need to be all polling from the same queue so that you can distribute the processing load.

Answer (score 0):

As other people noted there is not enough information in your email for us to help. One guide I can point you to for storage is a scalability and performance checklist which has some good tips in it. See here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/.